# import multiple xml with t-sql (2005)

Tags: sql

i do have the select for one file in the folder , 
can anyone help me on how to select all the files in the folder for the import?

```
SELECT MACHINE = XmlContent.value('(/recordedData/machine)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        RecordingDate = XmlContent.value('(/recordedData/date)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        RecordingTime = XmlContent.value('(/recordedData/hour)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        VariableName = XVar.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        VariableValue = XVar.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(XmlContent AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'C:\tmp\20130918_0932_ZSK40-2.xml',

     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(XmlContent)
     ) AS T(XmlContent)
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlContent.nodes('/recordedData/CollectedData/variable') AS XTbl(XVar)
```

it should be a trick on the filepath i think. apreciate the help!

Comment: the files have the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the `xp_cmdshell` if it is not disabled on your server. Essentially you will be able to run `dir` command through it and work around the query. You can make it like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @t table (cmdLineResult varchar(100))
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir C:\tmp\*.xml'
declare @left nvarchar(4000) = N'SELECT MACHINE = XmlContent.value(''(/recordedData/machine)[1]'',    ''varchar(50)''),
    RecordingDate = XmlContent.value(''(/recordedData/date)[1]'', ''varchar(50)''),
    RecordingTime = XmlContent.value(''(/recordedData/hour)[1]'', ''varchar(50)''),
    VariableName = XVar.value(''(Name)[1]'', ''varchar(50)''),
    VariableValue = XVar.value(''(Value)[1]'', ''varchar(50)'')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(XmlContent AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
 BULK '
declare @right nvarchar(4000) = N',
 SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(XmlContent)
 ) AS T(XmlContent)
CROSS APPLY 
    XmlContent.nodes(''/recordedData/CollectedData/variable'') AS XTbl(XVar)'
SELECT @sql += ' UNION ALL ' + @left + '''' + cmdLineResult + '''' + @right FROM @t
SET @sql = SUBSTRING (@sql,12,len(@sql)-12)
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

What you need to check here is:
- at the moment I'm unable to check how the output of xp_cmdshell will look like. You may need to adjust the definition of `@t` and maybe add `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` statement that is in the 3rd line from the bottom. There may also be minor issues here and there as I'm writing it from the head. I hope however it will give you at the very least good idea how to approach the problem.

Comment: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 18
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 19
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 20
Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".   there are the outputs so far. Trying now to investigate ...

Comment: managed to get a result:
     Volume in drive C is System
     Volume Serial Number is 806F-BF63
    NULL
     Directory of C:\tmp
    NULL
    18.09.2013  09:32             2.656 20130918_0932_ZSK40-2.xml
    18.09.2013  10:32             3.249 20130918_1032_ZSK70.xml
    21.09.2013  05:32             2.716 20130921_0532_ZSK40-2.xml
               3 File(s)          8.621 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   4.372.721.664 bytes free
    NULL

Comment: i seem to get the list of the temp directory with the script. any further help please?